# How can I configure spark-submit (or DataProc) to download maven dependencies (jars) from GitHub packages?

Tags: apache-spark, ivy, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-submit, github-package-registry

I am trying to get `spark-submit` (via GCP DataProc) to download maven dependencies from a GitHub packages repository.

Adding `spark.jars.repositories=https://myuser:mytoken@maven.pkg.github.com/myorg/my-maven-packages-repo/` to the `spark-submit` command doesn't help...

The correct urls are accessed, but the files aren't downloaded (`https://maven.pkg.github.com/myorg/my-maven-packages.repo/myorg/mylibrary/1.0.0/library-1.0.0.jar`).

How can I get this working? (Without using uber-jars!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding:

`spark.jars.repositories=https://myuser:mytoken@maven.pkg.github.com/myorg/my-maven-packages-repo/` to the `spark-submit` command

add:

`--files=gs://my-bucket/github-ivysettings.xml`

and

`spark.jars.ivySettings=github-ivysettings.xml`

upload the following file (`github-ivysettings.xml`) to the bucket:

```xml
<ivysettings>  

  <settings defaultResolver="default"/>

  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-public.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-shared.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-local.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-main-chain.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-default-chain.xml"/>

  <credentials
      host="maven.pkg.github.com" realm="GitHub Package Registry"
      username="myuser" passwd="mytoken"
      />
  <resolvers>
      <ibiblio
          name="private-github"
          m2compatible="true" useMavenMetadata="true" usepoms="true"
          root="https://maven.pkg.github.com/myorg/my-maven-packages-repo/"
          pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
      />
    <chain name="default" returnFirst="true" checkmodified="true">
      <resolver ref="local" />
      <resolver ref="shared" />
      <resolver ref="public" />
      <resolver ref="private-github" />
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

This will preserve the current search order (local, shared, public) and then search in your private repository.

Note that the realm is important, so if you use this for a different private repository, change the host, the root and the realm.